# Scrollable content with fixed header

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I would like to have a container with a fixed header and scrollable content. Here is the HTML and CSS I have set up for this

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Link to codepen: http://codepen.io/robkom/pen/XKMQGM

As you can see, the header is fixed and overlaps the scrollbar (when visible). What I want is for the scrollbar to push the header to the left (like it does with the content) and still remain at the top of the container when I scroll.

Fixed elements are removed from the normal document flow and positioned relative to the viewport, so I'm not sure if a solution using `position: fixed` is viable, but is there any way to achieve this result?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
http://codepen.io/hardikjain/pen/gMmJVr

Comment: No; in that case, the header is completely above the scrollbar, whereas I want the header to be beside the scrollbar like the content below it. I want the content and header to have the same width, but for the header to remain stuck to the top when you scroll.

Comment: What's the browser you are using? Cause I think I'm not seeing what you described..

Comment: I am using Chrome 50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a trick, using a wrapper in the header.

I forced scroll on the header, making the wrapper size according to content, then I simply increased the header with 50px to make sure all the different browsers' scroll bar sizes are covered and used the same amount on the wrapper to push it back into view.

Doing it like this, you don't have to worry about individual scroll bar width adjustment (or use script).

I also changed the header to absolute position so it positions with the container, but you can of course switch back to fixed if you need that.

*Updated*

*Firefox doesn't show scroll bar for small heights, so adding `margin/padding-top` as shown below makes it work*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  height: 20px;
  margin-top: -20px;   /* Firefox doesn't show scrollbar for small   */
  padding-top: 20px;   /* heights, so these two lines make it work  */
}
.header .wrapper {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      Header      
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
      <li>Content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: @cornflakes24 Will check in my FF soon in a sec.

Comment: @cornflakes24 Obviously a bug in Firefox (or by design) not showing scroll on smaller height's ... updated my answer with a fix

Comment: @cornflakes24 Were that update to your satisfaction?

Comment: Both answers work for me now, but I'm going with this one since I don't need to use JS.

Comment: @cornflakes24 Thanks for grammar update ... English is not my first language, missing verbs and possessive nouns from time to time :)

Answer (score 1):

This is kinda hacky solution but only one I can think of:

```
.container {
  margin-top: 200px;
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /*1*/
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; right: 17px; /*2*/
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

1. Use transform hack to create [new stacking context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering) meaning header will be fixed to `.container` instead of document.
2. Use `left` and `right` to set up header width minus scrollbar width (or you can do this: `width: calc(100% - 17px)`).

   I'm using magic number here since scrollbar width is 17px on [most modern browsers](http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/browser-scrollbar-width.php). You can calculate this value and set inline using JS (Bootstrap is doing this in their [modal](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js#L279-L286)).

**EDIT:** As noted in comments, translate hack is not needed as changing position to absolute (and setting container to `position: relative`) also works. Here is JS for retriving scrollbar width:

```
function getScrollbarWidth() {
    var scrollDiv = document.createElement('div');
    scrollDiv.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
    document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);
    var scrollbarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
    document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);
    return scrollbarWidth;  
};

function setElementWidth(elem) {
  var offset = getScrollbarWidth();
  elem.style.right = offset + 'px';
}

var header = document.querySelector('.header');
setElementWidth(header);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/zBwOEW)

Comment: You don't need to make a `fixed` behave like an `absolute` using the transform hack, just make the header `absolute` ... and using a fixed width will either hide some part of wider scroll bars (like FF) or show a gap between the header and scroll (like Edge), so if you could show a script version would be great